# Changing DocumentRoot in Apache2 on Mac Sierra

Tags: apache, configuration, configuration-files

I want to change the DocumentRoot for my Apache Server as I keep my files for Web Development in another location. The default Document Root is

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
```

I changed that to :

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/blah/Documents/project"
```

I also changed :

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
MultiviewsMatch Any

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride None

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to this:

```
<Directory "/Users/blah/Documents/project">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
MultiviewsMatch Any
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride None

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

However when i run localhost on my terminal I get the error:
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
I read through many previous posts regarding similar errors and saw that it was necessary to change permission of the folder. So I did that too. I can't seem to find out what is wrong. This is what comes up when I run ls -la in my project folder:

```
  total 24
drwxrwxrwx  5 raveen  staff  170 Oct 16 13:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 raveen  staff  204 Oct 15 20:09 ..
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 raveen  staff  438 Oct 16 15:17 index.cgi
-rwxrwxrwx  1 raveen  staff   90 Oct 15 22:56 mongo1.php
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 raveen  staff  372 Oct 16 13:37 mongo1.py
```

Comment: change ownership to _www:_www and you should  be fine

Comment: I changed User from _www to my name in the httpd.conf. Seems to have worked. Thanks for the pointer though :)